# Python DFS, can't figure out why return list is empty if using append/pop() but works for []+[] in recursive call

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, permutation, depth-first-search

can someone plz tell me why this code generate empty "res" variable? If uncomment the commented line and remove below will be working fine.

Codes not work:

```
class Solution(object):
    def dfs(self, nums, res, line):
        if not nums:
            print(line)
            res.append(line)
            return

        for i, num in enumerate(nums):
            line.append(num)
            # self.dfs(nums[:i]+nums[i+1:], res, line+[num])  
            self.dfs(nums[:i]+nums[i+1:], res, line)
            line.pop()

    def permute(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        res = []
        self.dfs(nums, res, [])
        print(res)
        return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Solution().permute([1,2])
```

Works fine if changing to:

```
 for i, num in enumerate(nums):
     self.dfs(nums[:i]+nums[i+1:], res, line+[num])
```

except using append/pop for passing the DFS. Even the "line" variable before appending to "res" is correct.

Does it have something to do with referencing? The only thing I could think of is whatever passed to res got cleaned up. I would really appreciate if someone could show me the link to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your guessing is correct. Just like Java, list in python is copy-by-reference. Consider the following example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
a.append(4)
print(b)
```

You will get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Thus, one easy way to fix the code is that replacing the `res.append(line)` in dfs() right before return into:

```
res.append(line[:])
```

Basically, `line[:]` will create a separate list object. You can see more information in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python).

Comment: thanks for your answer. so in this example, after DFS call finished, line variable got cleaned up so does the one in the res[]. but why the new list object "list+[num]" doesn't get cleaned up? are they the same type of local variables that only exist in the DFS call?

Comment: No, like what I said, if the passing argument is a list (or an object in general), it is pass-by-reference, that means the physical object is still there after the end of the function call, i.e., dfs(). I'm not too sure about this part, but I believe python implements some garbage collection mechanisms. Unless the list object is not referenced by any variable, the object will keep alive.

Comment: Python call semantics are [not call by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) because the receiving end gets the object, not a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Python function call semantics:

- Are *not pass-by-reference*. The receiving end does not need to de-reference it.
- Are *not pass-by-value*. There is no copy made of the value.
- May best be described as **pass by object**. The object itself is passed to the function; not a reference, not a copy, the very object itself.

See Frederik Lundh's [article about call by object semantics](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm). The Wikipedia article for this names it “[call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)” and attributes Barbara Liskov with coining that term.

This means that any container object you pass as a parameter will be present in the function as the same object, and **modifications there will persist** in the container object. The same is true of any mutable object.

So, if you want to modify a container passed in, don't modify it directly. Create a copy (usually by calling the type, e.g. `list`, to get a new instance), and modify that.

If the function's purpose is to generate a new container, it should create its own instance and *return* that copy.

So I think the `dfs` function is poorly designed. It should instead do something like:

```python
def dfs(nums, line):
    result = []

    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        line.append(num)
        result.extend(dfs(nums[:i]+nums[i+1:], line))
        line.pop()
    else:
        print(line)
        result.append(line)

    return result
```